# problem with zoom feature in QGIS 3.0

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, zoom

I am having a strange problem--currently using QGIS 3.03. I cannot zoom to any of my point layers (can't use zoom to selected, zoom to layer, etc.)  But I CAN zoom to my polygon layers.  Both are shapefiles, both are WGS84 unprojected (EPSG4325). Does anyone know what might be going on?

I saw a related question that said to disable a plugin called Tile Map Scale, but I have no such plugin installed.  Just as an experiment, I disabled and uninstalled all plugins, and am still having the same issue.

Are there perhaps any other zoom or scale settings I might be overlooking?

Comment: When you say you "can't use zoom to layer", do you mean the option is greyed out, or invisible, or it doesn't zoom to the layer properly?

Comment: For me "Zoom to layer" and "zoom to selected" does seem a bit wrong, zooming in a bit too far so that some of my features are outside the window. For points *and* polygons. Hmmm

Comment: Have you got the "Magnifier" set to anything apart from 100% in the bottom status line? This seems to upset the zoom...

Comment: Do your shapefiles have a spatial index?

Comment: It doesn't zoom.  I select "zoom to layer" for these 3 point layers and nothing happens.  But it works for other layers.  Yes, they have a spatial index.  I can't figure it out.

Comment: Looks like I discovered the problem.  The extent was set wrong.  I'm unsure how it got that way, but when I re-saved and set it to match the extent of the other layers, the zoom started working.